# HTML in Tumblr, tumblr theme coding with colour changed hyperlink for email and shortened url

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am trying to change the html in the description so that my hyperlink to open email client still works as well as a hyperlink to a google map pin. I would like the hyperlinks to be white as the background is blue. Please see the code below that i have in the description box:

```
<c>grabbing companies by their...
<br>
<br>
<a href="change-hyperlink-color" style="color: #FFFFFF" href="mailto:info@gobootstrap.ca">info@gobootstrap.ca </a>· 647-465-5114 · <a/ href="change-hyperlink-color.php" style="color: #FFFFFF" 73 Bathurst Street - 4th Floor</a>
<br>
<br>
creative. strategic. development.</font>
```

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear. What is it exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, what I am looking to do is change the colour of the hyperlink that I have for the hyperlink for email and for an outside web address which is blue(the autonmatic colour for links) to white

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tag to open the email client

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>
```

And then for the google maps page you just need to link to the city/place you want in the href `<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place">A place</a>`

Comment: Right, I have that, just need to change the colour of the hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks Guys. got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have some strange markup in your code.

Here is a working example using css selectors.

```
a {
   color:#FF0000; // set all hyperlinks to red
}

[href^="mailto"] {
    color:#FFFFFF; // set any hyperlink which starts with mailto in the href to white
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/prd844gy/)